# Only have remote desktop sessions password protected

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a computer on a remote location which is stripped down to the use of a single application (explorer disabled and no input devices except touch-screen). 
The application starts automatically on a reboot and therefore the user is not password protected. How can i password-protect RDP sessions for this user/session but leave the 'physical' access to the device unprotected? 
Is it possible? 
I'm aware of TeamViewer but this should be the last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Turns out there is a solution that does not require to enable the built in vpn-server.

- run "netplwiz"
- uncheck "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer."

You now don't need to enter the password and the login screen is bypassed on boot up. If you connect via remote-desktop you'll have to provide the credentials as usual. Just keep in mind that you'll have to reboot the computer after a remote desktop session as otherwise the computer asks the person infront of it for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to enable the built-[in VPN server, which will not require
installing additional software.

The procedure is as follows :

1. Run `ncpa.cpl`
2. In the "Network Connections" window, press once the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to show the full menus, then open the File menu and select New Incoming Connection.
3. Create a new and limited user account by clicking the "Add someone" button.
4. Check the option of Through the Internet, and click Next.
5. In the networking software page, select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4), and click Properties.
6. Check the option of Allow callers to access my local area network.
7. Under IP address assignment, click Specify IP addresses, and specify
   a limited IP address range.
8. Click OK.
9. Click Allow access.
10. Click Close.

For a more detailed write-up including screenshots see the article
[How to set up a VPN server on Windows 10](http://pureinfotech.com/setup-vpn-server-windows-10/).

Comment: Is there something against setting up a 2nd Password Protected User on the Remote PC and just use this one for RDP?

Comment: @konqui: This would cause the current user to be logged-out.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i was not aware of that feature. In the end i found a solution that is more suitable for this case.